# rails associations, retrieve conversation between 2 users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a rails app using postgres database, and I'm trying to add a feature where 2 users can directly chat with each other. I a user model and conversation model, and they are related by `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. I also has a joint table for  this relationship.

```
class CreateJoinTableUserConversation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :conversations do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

My goal is when a user clicks on the link to chat with another user, if there is no conversation object related to these 2 users, then create one. Otherwise retrieve the existing conversation. How can I do this with either active record or a sql call? I don't want to have to iterate through all the conversations and perform a check on whether or not these 2 users are in `conversation.users`, because that will take forever when there are a lot of conversations. Is there a way to access the joint table to somehow retrieve the record of a conversation that has 2 particular users associated with it?

**EDIT**

here is the table from the schema.

```
  create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

here are the models:

```
    class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
    end
```

Comment: Before I go and spout off an answer, can you post the schema for your Conversation model?

Comment: and please at-mention me when you do so i get notified.  thanks!

Comment: @JoshDeeden ok I've added the schema as well as the models

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, you can use `has_many: through` relationship. Which will give you joint table model as in your case Conversation model.So that you can perform where query on your joint table using model.

But you will also need to add foreign keys of both the users in join table.